# VLOOKUP to return value of 2 to 3 columns

Tags: excel

I am trying to search for vlookup formula to return 2 or 3 value of columns.

For example, if I vlookup on Column F2 Sku to A:D in one formula I want to automatically give the value also on column H2 product 2 and column i2 product 3
so that I will no longer do same vlook up on the next column.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I had no idea what you wanted (and two copies of the same unnecessarily large area of real estate was not helping) but I think I may now understand. In G1:

```
=VLOOKUP($F1,$A:$D,COLUMN()-5,0)
```

copy that across to I1 and then G1:I1 down to suit.

By anchoring the column for the lookup value dragging across does not change the cell. By anchoring the columns for the lookup range (and selecting all that may be required), the left hand column remains the one that may contain the lookup value and the array is wide enough to cover all the possible locations (ie whichever column).

I think what you wanted was to avoid having to write a different formula for each column, where basically only the column number in the [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) function needed to change.

This I have managed by making use of the [COLUMN](https://support.office.com/en-GB/article/COLUMN-function-44e8c754-711c-4df3-9da4-47a55042554b) function. Handily, with no parameter (ie as `COLUMN()`) this returns the numeric value for the cell in which the function is placed. With the formula starting in G1, the relevant column number is 7 initially. Since we only want `2` for the VLOOKUP, I deducted 5. Dragged across, the column number increase 8 to 9 so the VLOOKUP function then receives `3` for ColumnH and `4` for ColumnI.

Comment: i thought that there is a chance that i don't need to put formula in column H and I